# cannot read property 'length' error occured when i performing following operation

Tags: javascript

When i performing following operation it shows Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined.
Can any one please help me.

```
var events = [
  {
    "EventsCalendarID": 21,
    "AdminUserName": "ManjitSingh",
    "StartDate": "2014-08-27 12:00 AM",
    "EndDate": "8/28/2014 12:00:00 AM",
    "Timezone": "Europe/London",
    "Message": "mabkja",
    "IsApproved": true,
    "UserID": "70348398-9b8e-48a2-bbfc-c2474146d5d5",
    "User": null
  },
  {
    "EventsCalendarID": 22,
    "AdminUserName": "ManjitSingh",
    "StartDate": "2014-08-29 12:00 AM",
    "EndDate": "8/29/2014 1:00:00 AM",
    "Timezone": "Europe/London",
    "Message": "ffd",
    "IsApproved": true,
    "UserID": "70348398-9b8e-48a2-bbfc-c2474146d5d5",
    "User": null
  },
  {
    "EventsCalendarID": 23,
    "AdminUserName": "ManjitSingh",
    "StartDate": "2014-08-29 12:00 AM",
    "EndDate": "8/29/2014 1:00:00 AM",
    "Timezone": "Europe/London",
    "Message": "fndmms",
    "IsApproved": true,
    "UserID": "70348398-9b8e-48a2-bbfc-c2474146d5d5",
    "User": null
  }
];

function success(events) {
  var ev = [];
  $.each(events.items, function (i, v) {
    ev.push({
      title: v.Message,
      start:v.StartDate,
      end:v.EndDate,
      id: v.EventsCalendarID
    });
  });
}
```

Comment: sorry its a mistake when righting in stack over flow.its added in my code but it shows the error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apart from what arghbleargh said (which is also correct), you can also (alternatively) use

```
events.forEach(function (i, v) {
    ev.push({ title: i.Message, start: i.StartDate, end: i.EndDate, id: i.EventsCalendarID });
});
```

Here's the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/ymrsxh2h/ which i used

Hope this also helps :)

Answer (score 3):

It looks like the error is in this line

```
                $.each(events.items, function (i, v) {
```

This is going to iterate over `events.items`, which is undefined (since `events` is just an array, it has no property `items`). `$.each` tries to read the property `events.items.length` in its attempt to iterate over `events.items`, which explains your error. Probably you wanted instead:

```
                $.each(events, function (i, v) {
```